# Wagtail returns 500 error on Debug = False

Tags: wagtail

I can't seem to get my site to display when I set Debug = False in my settings file after getting it to run using a standard setup of wagtail start . If I runserver it runs fine. I change the setting to Debug = False and my site shows the 500 error page.

Just the basic settings file:

```
from .base import *

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
#DEBUG = True
DEBUG = False

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'c1=mbs2t*!^omg&i0xfo_=mle)%_oegt-&@gn)vx5cs0foe%l9'

# SECURITY WARNING: define the correct hosts in production!
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'


try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Django 2.2.1
Wagtail 2.5

Answer (score 4):

It turns out I had to collectstatic files.

Comment: Was this after an upgrade to wagtail by chance? That is what happened to me. Glad I came across your question and answer!

Answer (score 2):

When Django runs with `DEBUG=False` you won't get the yellow error pages. That doesn't mean those errors are not raised.

Just configure logging and inspect the logs.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#django-s-default-logging-configuration

Without a traceback it is hard to solve any issue.

This is how you log to a file:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

This is the Django default logging: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/utils/log.py

Answer (score 0):

I think this same thing caught me a while back. It's because the browser looks for a /favicon.ico file and for some reason Wagtail or Django tries to pass it to a view instead of just 404ing. Try to add the following in the head of your base.html template and see how it goes. Correcting the link to the file path below as needed.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

Comment: That didn't fix it for me. Still getting the 500 error template.

Comment: It appears if I collectstatic then my site runs. However, if I map the static file outside of the project and collectstatic, it will not run under DEBUG = False. I'm not sure how to go about setting up my settings file. The collectstatic runs, the files show up under DEBUG = True as the right urls. But setting DEBUG = False puts up the 500 error.

Comment: Didn't fix it for me either... Getting the 500 error without any error / logs anywhere.

Comment: @Fonz001 Do you have logging set up in whatever settings file you're running off of? With debug off it won't automatically log anything until you configure logging.

Comment: @Neum that didn't help. I have logging setup. I did notice that the admin area gives a proper stacktrace: 

`
Internal Server Error: /nl/admin/images/
...
  File "/home/wagtail/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 420, in stored_name
    raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'wagtailadmin/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js`

However, the frontend just gives this as stacktrace:

`Internal Server Error: /`